# How to attribute each datapoint to a specific buffer ID

Tags: qgis, export, buffer, unique-id

I have many datapoints within 57 buffers in GIS (see picture for an example of a couple of the. buffers with datapoint inside). I need to be able to analyze each buffer separately, and therefore need a unique ID representing which data point comes from which buffer.

If I don't 'export by location' iteratively, and just have one layer with all the points extracted from the buffer, is there a way to make GIS attribute each datapoint with an ID that indicates which buffer that data point is within?

[image: 57 buffers]

Comment: As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to only ask one question.

Comment: You don't say what GIS system you are using! In ArcMap this would be the spatial Join tool.

Comment: Apologies, it's QGIS.

Comment: Look at this [tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your datapoints layer (red in the screenshot below), create a new attribute with field calculator using this expression:

```
array_first (overlay_nearest('buffer',$id))
```

Replace `buffer` with the name of your buffer layer. Where two buffers overlap, you'll get the id of the "closer" one: the one with the nearest centroid.

*Red datapoints labeled with the id of the buffer:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks - this answer works, however I will be doing this in two separate layers, and when I try this method the buffer ID begins at "1" for both layers, when in reality I need the buffer IDs from the second layer to begin at "58" (as there are 57 buffers in the first layer). Is there a way I can alter the ID of this second layer?

Comment: Yes. You can create a new field with field calculator, give it a name (let's say `id_new`) and use the expreesion `$id+57` to create the values. $id 1 will get a value of 58, $id 2 a value of 59 etc. Than in the expression from above,  at the end replace `$id` with the name of the new attribute (like `id_new` in my case).

Comment: Thanks so much! Out of curiosity, in the "array_first (overlay_nearest('buffer',$id))" expression, where does the "$id" come from? Does QGIS automatically generate this id for each buffer, or is it based on the row number, or something else?

Comment: Yes, $id is automatically created for each feature - it's kind of numbering the features for identification purpose.